# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Launcher when running boot repl

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to run `boot repl` and I get the following error.

```
                                                               java.lang.Thread.run Thread.java:  832   
                                 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run  ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  630
                                  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker  ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1130
                                                java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run          FutureTask.java:  264
                                                                                ...                               
                                                clojure.core/binding-conveyor-fn/fn                 core.clj: 1938
```

Skipped a lot of lines here

```
                                                    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass         ClassLoader.java:  589
                                                                                ...                               
                                                  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass      URLClassLoader.java:  435
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Launcher
      clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: sun.misc.Launcher
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following a guide on how to set up boot from [spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/clojure/README.html#quick-start-with-boot). The information there was outdated or wrong. The problem was that in my `~/.boot/profile.boot` To solve the issue I had to change dependencies from what was on spacemacs site to what was on [refactor-nrepl](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/refactor-nrepl).

```
(require 'boot.repl)

(swap! boot.repl/*default-dependencies* conj
       '[refactor-nrepl "2.5.1"] 
       '[cider/cider-nrepl "0.25.9"])

(swap! boot.repl/*default-middleware* conj
       'refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor)
```